# Как заполнить скрытое поле формы значением переменной?

Tags: jquery, форма

Есть форма в contact form 7

```html
<div class="contact">
  <div class="section-top">
    <div class="contact-head">
      Запрос вывода средств
    </div>
    <div class="one-half u-us-page-content">
      [text* your-name placeholder "Имя"]
    </div>
    <div class="one-half last">
      [email* your-email placeholder "E-mail"]
    </div>
    <div class="contact-nose">
      Мне понадобится:
    </div>
    <div class="u-us-form">
      [radio radio-581 use_label_element default:1 "Всё " "Часть"]
    </div>
    <div>
      [group group-826] [number* number-858 placeholder "Количество"] [/group]
    </div>
  </div>
  [submit "Отправить запрос"]
</div>
[dynamichidden dynamichidden-2 "CF7_get_current_user key='ID'"]
```

Есть скрытое поле `[dynamichidden dynamichidden-2 "CF7_get_current_user key='ID'"]` которое заполняется с помощью дополнения Dynamic Text Extension к Contact Form 7. Есть переменная `$fallWithAll` значение которой выводится на той же странице что и форма.
Как значением этой переменной заполнить скрытое поле формы?

Comment: если не ошибаюсь, то так `[dynamichidden dynamichidden-2 "CF7_get_current_user key='ID'" "GET_fallWithAll"]`, ну или непосредственно через js можно

Comment: Вариант `[dynamichidden dynamichidden-2 "CF7_get_current_user key='ID'" "GET_fallWithAll"]`, к сожалению, не работает. Непосредственно через js не подскажете как?

Comment: Можно добавить эл-ту id, к примеру, и в этот эл-т вставлять значение посредством js. `[dynamichidden dynamichidden-2 "CF7_get_current_user key='ID'" id:elemID] ... $('#elemID').val('<?=$fallWithAll?>');`